# how can i set route name in javascript code in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, forms, routes, runtime

I want to assign/set route in javascript code. I have javascript method which take route name in parameter and I want to assign that parameter in route as below.

function assign_route(route_name){

var url = "{{ route('+route_name+') }}";

OR As below

var url = "{{ route('old_url') }}";
url = url.replace('old_url', route_name);

}

Comment: Route names are generated in PHP code which runs before JavaScript can run. If you're trying to generate the route name based on some JS variable you compute after the page loads you'd need to request the route name from the server via some sort of AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

You can specify named routes by chaining the name method onto the route definition:

```
Route::get('user/profile', function () { // })->name('profile');
```

You can specify route names for controller actions:

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');
```

Comment: Thanks. I've set route in web.php file. I have a method in controller.. I want to submit form in different route passing route in javascript function, and submit form in that JS function at runtime.

<a href="#" onclick="manage_courses_task('sessionalmarks.task.get')" Manage Course</a>

<a href="#" onclick="manage_courses_task('sessionalmarks.task.get')" Manage Course</a>
my html form 
    <form id="update-form" >
        <input type="hidden" id="course_id" name="course_id" />
        @csrf
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this inside your javascript function:

```
var uri = "{{ route('routeName', ':variable') }}";
uri = uri.replace(':variable', yourvariable);
```

Comment: Sir, it will change the parameter of routeName, actually i want to change routeName at runtime by passing different routes
var uri = "{{ route('routeName',) }}";
uri = uri.replace('routeName', mynewroute);

Comment: try putting your roue in routeName, routeName is your route form web whatever you have set the name to.